# The best way to keep the main method running

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I used a way to keep the main method running.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure it's the best way.

Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: Why do you need it to keep running? What is it you're waiting for?

Comment: I have some services that require the main method to load.

Comment: It´s definitly the simplest way but if it is a new software you are writing change to a event driven architecture so there are allways shaddulers/timers/listeners which are waiting and keep things running.

Comment: This is called a "spin-wait" and it is an anti-pattern (high CPU). You could for example use a blocking call to ReadLine so just need to hit enter to end the program. Another approach would be to have it block on some kind of WaitHandle that gets signaled by other threads ( for example to implement remote shutdown by Network IO )

Comment: Or use a very *long* sleep instead of a 1ms sleep. Currently your loop is never going to quit, so why not just have a single `sleep` call that would sleep for longer than the machine is likely to be powered on?

Comment: You can use a `CountDownLatch(1)` to wait until some other process notifies your main method that it should stop by calling countDown. If you have other non daemon threads, even if the main method will exit, the application won't stop until those finish their job

Comment: To add to Jon's approach: [Thread.sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) takes a `long`, that would make for a maximum sleep time of Long.MAX_VALUE. That should be enough for most scenarios. ( ~292471208.67 years)

Comment: @JonSkeet It's 1 second, not 1 millisecond.

Comment: @shmosel: Whoops, yes - sorry for not noticing that. I'd still say that sleeping for a million years would be better :)

Comment: @shmosel When Jon Skeet makes a thread sleep, it sleeps until Jon Skeet is ready for it to wake up.

Comment: @JonSkeet nearly 292.5 million years ... if my math is correct. :D

Comment: @Fildor: I'd suggest that beyond 100 years the chances of it making any difference are negligible :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Absolutely agreed. I was just staggered about how long that actually is, when I calculated it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. 'Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE)' is this the best way?

Comment: It's a better way than the current. "Best" always depends on your definition of "good".

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to hold the main() Thread without entering into Terminated/Dead state.
Below are the two methods I often use-

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Stop me if you can");
   Thread.currentThread().join(); // keep the main running
  }
```

The other way is to create the ReentrantLock and call wait() on it:

```
public class Test{
private static Lock mainThreadLock = new ReentrantLock();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Stop me if you can");
    synchronized (mainThreadLock) {
        mainThreadLock.wait();
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use a ExecutorService and submit a task that waits for reading your services's output.

```
package demo;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class TaskDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        System.out.println("Hello");

        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        Runnable task = () -> {
            try {
                //Loop to read your services's output
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("This is from Task");
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        threadPool.execute(task);
        //Wait for the task to finish and shutdow the pool
        threadPool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Frank.Dai: This way, the main method will keep running until the task finish so just keep the task running as long as you want.

Comment: You need a new thread in this way, and I think it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: @Frank.Dai: I think in case we want to wait for something, the best way to do is using a thread, because it will not block our main thread to do other tasks. When the waiting thread finish its task it sends a signal to the main thread.

Answer (score -2):

You have many choices, Some of them:

- Simple thread
- TimerTask
- ScheduledExecutorService

Simple Thread:

```
public class Task {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      final long timeInterval = 1000;
      Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          while (true) {
              System.out.println("Running Task ...");
                try {
                   Thread.sleep(timeInterval);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
          }
       }
      };
      Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
      thread.start();
  }
 }
```

TimerTask:

```
 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;
 public class Task {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   System.out.println("Running Task ...");
               }
          };
          Timer timer = new Timer();
          long delay = 0;
          long intevalPeriod = 1000; 
          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay,intevalPeriod);
      } 
 }
```

ScheduledExecutorService:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Task {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
               System.out.println("Running Task ...");
             }
        };
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors
                .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is one way to maintain the main the java instance to run until you want to exit. Using the GUI to do that:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jFrame.setSize(480, 260);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    //do some task here
}
```

Comment: @Fildor he wants to keep the main runing, I think it can

Comment: Sure, just saying. The side effect of this solution is a GUI, not sure if that's wanted. But not knowing whether it is _not_ wanted, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Why to introduce a new dependency to Swing?! Without knowing for sure if he *has* GUI, you should not even suggest this solution.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Just one way to let him know, and I didn't say it's the best solution

Comment: Downvoted due to the last paragraph: a daemon thread is precisely the opposite: it's a thread that *won't* prevent the JVM from shutting down. If the thread running main is the only non-daemon thread, the JVM will shut down.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry , My mistake

Comment: @Jaycee If he does *not* have a GUI, it is not only "not the best solution", it is simply a *wrong* solution. Introducing weird redundant dependencies without thinking is always a wrong solution.

Comment: @HonzaZidek As I know, the JFrame class is embedded in jdk